# How many unique combinations of sets can we get?

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, prime-numbers, finite-rings

Starting with $x$, which is a positive integer or zero, and $y$ a second positive integer or zero, with $y \ne x$, we can create lists.

Set $p$ a prime greater than 2, $\alpha = (p-1)/2$, and $\beta=\lfloor \log_2p \rfloor$. Then we can create 2 ordered sets; a set using $x$ and a set using $y$:

$$\left( x^\alpha, (x+a_1)^\alpha, (x+a_2)^\alpha, \dots (x+a_\beta)^\alpha \right) \pmod p$$
$$\left( y^\alpha, (y+a_1)^\alpha, (y+a_2)^\alpha, \dots (y+a_\beta)^\alpha \right) \pmod p$$

...where $a_k$ is a natural less than or equal to $p$. Note that unless $x$ or $y$ equals $-a_j$ for some $j$, each entry is either $1$ or $-1$ mod $p$ (depending on whether the number being exponentiated is a quadratic residue of nonresidue), so there are at most $2^{\beta+1}$ possible tuples not containing $0$; note also that $2^{\beta+1}$ is between $p$ and $2p$.

**My question is:  If we are trying to maximize the amount of unique sets, and we are allowed to choose the $a_k$'s any way we like in order to maximize the number of unique sets, how many unique sets can we get?**

**NOTES**

This question is similar to ["Is this sliding window unique?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1017883/is-this-sliding-window-unique), except here we are allowed to pick $a_k$ values in order to try to maximize the number of unique sets and reduce the number of matching "tuples".

Comment: "maximize the amount of unique sets", as $x$ and $y$ range over what? all positive integers? if so, then there will be infinitely many distinct sets so created.

Comment: @GregMartin:  Sorry - I've added that we're calculating modulo $p$.  $x$ and $y$ are non-negative integers less than $p$.  I'm hoping to get very close, if not equal, to $p$ distinct sets.

Comment: Ok, this makes more sense now. I've made some edits - feel free to revert them if you don't think they're correct or helpful. One question: are you letting $x$ vary over all residue classes modulo $p$, and counting the nunber of distinct tuples you get? If so, what role does $y$ play?

Comment: @GregMartin:  Actually, thanks for the edits and help!  For this question, I'm attempting to do all work modulo $p$.  Essentially, I'm trying to get as close as possible to $p$ distinct sets.  We can view the elements of the sets as essentially a form of binary numbers, with the two possible digits as $1$ or $-1$ modulo $p$, with the exception that some elements of the set will be $0$.  So another way to think of the question is that we're essentially trying to get as many unique "binary numbers", if you will, as possible.  There should be a maximum of $p$ values (when all are unique).

Comment: @Greg Martin:  I've just realized I haven't really answered your question.  I'm letting $x$ and $y$ vary over all residue classes modulo $p$ - essentially I'm thinking of $x$ and $y$ as two integers greater than $-1$ and less than $p+1$.  They are independent of one another, and I see your point that the set containing $y$ may not be very relevant to the question.  I'm really just trying to describe that I'm trying to get $p$ distinct sets.

Comment: I doubt that there will be $p$ distinct sets for large $p$, no matter how you fix the $a_j$. The probabilistic heuristic described in the linked answer to the "sliding window" question can be done for this version as well, treating the $p^\beta$ choices of tuple as a bunch of different trials, but each trial is selecting a bunch of "binary numbers" independently at random and hoping for few collisions. I suggest working through that probability problem to form a conjecture.